# How to make an IF statement repeat itslef if it goes to else

Tags: excel, vba, loops, statements

I have this piece of code:

```
If IsEmpty(Cells(8, M8 + 9).Value) And IsEmpty(Cells(12, M8 + 9).Value) Then
    Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(8, M8 + 9).Value = info
    Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(12, M8 + 9).Value = "--------------"
    Sheets("Sheet3").Range(Cells(8, M8 + 9), Cells(12, M8 + 9)).Interior.Color = RColor
    M8 = M8 + 1
Else
    M8 = M8 + 1
End If
```

I was wondering if there is a way that when the first condition is not met and goes to the `Else` branch to add 1 to the `M8` variable. When it adds 1 to `M8` I want it to go back to the top and repeat the if statement with the new value of `M8`.

Comment: I think a `GoTo` statement is exactly what you're looking for. If you don't set your values in the else so that the if statement will eventually pass it will loop forever.

Comment: You should probably rename `M8` to something meaningful. If you have `M7`, `M6`, `M5`, `M4`, `M3`, `M2` and `M1` as well, you probably need an array instead of numbered variables. Usually when you think "I want something to repeat until a condition is met" then what you need is a loop.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use an `If`?  This would loop until the condition specified is no longer true; but as Gary noted above it's possible to get into an endless loop, so I've added an additional criteria to break the loop if it goes on for 100 iterations

```
iTried = 0
While IsEmpty(Cells(8, M8 + 9).Value) And IsEmpty(Cells(12, M8 + 9).Value) = True And iTried <=100
    Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(8, M8 + 9).Value = info
    Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(12, M8 + 9).Value = "--------------"
    Sheets("Sheet3").Range(Cells(8, M8 + 9), Cells(12, M8 + 9)).Interior.Color = RColor
    M8 = M8 + 1
Wend
' Now check WHY the loop ended... if the cells are empty and the counter is >100 throw a msgbox
If IsEmpty(Cells(8, M8 + 9).Value) And IsEmpty(Cells(12, M8 + 9).Value) = True And iTried >100 Then
    MsgBox "Too many tries; gave up!"
End If
```

Comment: The loop won't be endless. If `M8` is an `Integer` it will overflow when its value gets to 32768. It will take a little while longer if it's a `Long`, but it will eventually overflow.

Comment: Didn't think of that to be honest, but I'd still prefer to control its exit point myself, thanks for the clarification

Comment: I upvoted this answers as a loop is the prefered/better method.

Answer (score 2):

You need to come at this from the other direction.  If you need `M8` to meet a specific condition, make sure the condition is met *before* you do anything else:

```
Dim aborted As Boolean
Do While Not (IsEmpty(Cells(8, M8 + 9).Value) And IsEmpty(Cells(12, M8 + 9).Value))
    M8 = M8 + 1
    If M8 > 100 Then    'Or whatever your "give up" condition is
        aborted = True
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop

If Not aborted Then
    Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(8, M8 + 9).Value = info
    Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(12, M8 + 9).Value = "--------------"
    Sheets("Sheet3").Range(Cells(8, M8 + 9), Cells(12, M8 + 9)).Interior.Color = RColor
End If
```